# LinkedIn Full Info access + SDK

Tags: sdk, linkedin-api

I'm trying to find all the information from the users such as profile picture etc via the LinkedIn SDK, I currently got the following but i'm a bit stuck on how to get more information out of it .. Any idea?

```
$('.btn_linkedin').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Apply');
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
})

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, adding more arguments did the trick :). To get aditional field you can add them as query parameter. ex.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json
```